how to use git stash without roll my unstaged work work back to head?
I know whats git stash -k, and I try to find anything about and Ask AI but found nothing.
My goal is to quickly try new test changes on top of existing test changes without having to commit or stage them. Is there any other more convenient workflow for this operation, or is this behavior harmful and not recommended? Is “git add” avoidable? Or should I not avoid it?
Tried “git stash” and the -k option, but I need to use “git add” to stage it first

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. git stash is to put away your changes. You cannot use stash to "apply changes on top of existing changes". Can you maybe share an example and what you expect after each step?

My goal is to quickly try new test changes on top of existing test changes without having to commit or stage them. Change your goal. Making a commit temporarily is a lightweight operation. Commits and branches (branches are just names attached to individual commits) are the way to experiment with changes.

So just make a new branch with new commits, and if things don't work out, check out the original branch to erase it all and try again.

Use commits. You’ll get faster in time.

Thank you guys, I think I know what to do!

You can play with git apply  so that you can introduce and then remove random changes. So, to apply a random change into your working tree:
git show some-commit | git apply -

So you get those changes in... No commit involved... Index is not touched either.
Then to remove it
git show some-commit | git apply -r -

You could apply bigger things
git diff A..B | git apply -

Warning: this is flaky.... I would only do this for trivial things.... And I don't know how it deals with conflicts so use it with.a lot of caution.... Stashing your changes before running the apply is a much safer approach as when popping you keep the original stash if there are conflicts.

thanks! now I know commit is the right way
